# setInterval in not updating my timer variable in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, setinterval

```
var timer = 0; 
const [run, setRun] = useState(false);


useEffect(() => {

    if (run) {
      Toast.show("Timmer is running"+timer, Toast.LONG);
      var interval = setInterval(() => { timer++; }, 1000);
    } else {
      Toast.show("Timmer is stopped"+timer, Toast.LONG);
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [run]);

const runTimer = () => {
   setRun(!run);
} 


//JSX 

<Text onPress={runTimer} 
      style={{fontSize: 18, color: 'black', zIndex: 11, fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',}}>
    {timer}
</Text>
```

Here , while i click on text , i need the timer to start and pause when i click back , but its not updating timer at all.

Can someone help me out, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

timer is unable to receive the current timer value, i think you can declare `timer` as a state variable and then `setInterval(() => { setTimer(prev=>prev+1 }, 1000);`